# NullPointer Exception while getting an instance of sqlite singleton

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

below is my db helper class :

```
public class DbAllHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDb.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static DbAllHelper sInstance = null;

        public static DbAllHelper getInstance(Context context)
        {

                if (sInstance == null)
                {
                        sInstance = new DbAllHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
                }
                return sInstance;
        }

        private DbAllHelper(Context context)
        {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + usersTable + " "
                                + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + //0
                                "surname TEXT, " + //1
                                "name TEXT); "); //2
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {

        }

        public void insertUser(String name, String surname)
        {
                ContentValues userCV = new ContentValues();
                contactCV.put("surname", surname);
                contactCV.put("name", name);
                db.insert(usersTable, null, userCV );
        }
}
```

whenever I call `DbAllHelper db = DbAllHelper.getInstance(this);` from my activity. 
I get the following nullpointer.

> 10-17 21:05:13.889: E/AndroidRuntime(10025): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-17 21:05:13.889: E/AndroidRuntime(10025):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
>   10-17 21:05:13.889: E/AndroidRuntime(10025):    at com.myApp.DbAllHelper.getInstance(DbAllHelper.java:38)

Comment: remove ".getApplicationContext()", use only context.

Comment: well, it says like that in here : http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `context.getApplicationContext()`? Im pretty sure just using `context` would be enough.

Comment: following this example mates : http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Comment: Ok but thats kind of redundant getting a context from a context.

Comment: I will, just after 7 minutes, when SO will allow me :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling this in `OnClickListener`, So you must create new object from your `DbAllHelper` Class with constructor like this:

> DbAllHelper db = DbAllHelper.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

Additionaly change this part of your code to this:

> ```
>     public static DbAllHelper getInstance(Context context)
>     {
> ```

```
            if (sInstance == null)
            {
                    sInstance = new DbAllHelper(context);
            }
            return sInstance;
    }
```

Comment: If he would be in OnClickListener it wouldn't event compile.

Comment: whay not @tony9099 ? only you must use it with `MainActivity.this`. I have used it before.

Comment: exactly. thats why I was saying.